# Can i have some python code in second file and when i run the first file its like the code is inside the first file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have 2 python files and i want to run the second file in the first one like the code in the second file was inside the first file. Is this possible and if so how?

I dont know what to try please help. Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you copy paste the second file into the first file?

Comment: @InyoungKim김인영 that's a bad practice when it comes to code refactoring and separation of intentions

Comment: You shouldn't have skipped the Python tutorial: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just like how you can use `import` to import other python libraries (built-in or third-party), you can also import your own libraries/modules/files. if the two files are in the same directory, you can do `import file2` at the top of file one and run any of the functions or modules within it.

ex:

```py
# this is file_2

def main():
    print('this is from file_2')
```

```py
# this is file_1
import file_2

file_2.main()
```

If you then run file_1 (you could run `python file_1.py` from the terminal, or however you run it), it will print out 'this is from file_2'